# Portable way to include malloc_np.h

Tags: c, cmake, malloc, portability, freebsd

I'm using a third-party library which includes `malloc_np.h`. From what I found over internet, this means that the code was supposed to compile under FreeBSD, although simply changing the include to `malloc.h` made it compilable under Linux (Ubuntu 13.10).

Now I'm writing a CMake script for this library to generate appropriate make files (including NMake makefiles for MSVC 2010).

What is the best way to achieve portability in such a scenario?

My current solution is to test for:

```
${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "FreeBSD"
```

in the CMake script. Depending on the result I issue a

```
add_definitions (-DINCLUDE_MALLOC_H="#include <malloc[_np].h>")
```

command and use this macro in the source file instead of `#include <malloc_np.h>`.

Is this a good practice?

Comment: Neither `<malloc_np.h>` nor `<malloc.h>` is standard, so any code using them cannot be *completely* portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Generate time

Use `CheckIncludeFile*` modules:

```
include(CheckIncludeFileCXX)

check_include_file_cxx("malloc.h" have_malloc)

if(have_malloc)
  add_definitions(-DINCLUDE_MALLOC_H)
endif()
```

### Compile time

Use [boost.predef](https://github.com/boostorg/predef) library to detect os specific features

Comment: Isn't Boost specific to C++? The question is about C.

Comment: It turned out that the files including `malloc.h` where just using `free` and `malloc` so I think I'll just change the include to `stdlib.h`. But anyway thank you for your answer, @ruslo, I didn't know anything about those `CheckInclude*` modules!